# Jsp class not visible

Tags: java, class, jsp, tomcat, import

I'm trying to get my first jsp page running and it does not work as I expect it to.
I'm using Tomcat7 + Eclipse.

First I created my framework.java file and put it in: \ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\framework.

Then I successful compiled it so I got:
\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\framework\Layer1.class, Layer2.class, Layer3.class
Then i did the actual jsp file:

```
<%@ page import="framework.Layer1" %>
<%= Layer1.write() %>
```

Now, even Eclipse at this point gives me the warning: The type framework.Layer1 is not visible.
And when I run the page, naturally it says: The type framework.Layer1 is not visible.

What am I doing wrong here? I tried all tutorials I found and all had the same issue.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the right path, but you need to make sure **Layer1** is a public class.

So, your `Layer1` class **must** be something like:

```
package framework;
public class Layer1 {
    public String write() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
package framework;
class Layer1 { // do note the non-use of public keyword here
}
```

Comment: Yes, i tried that but then javac says: framework.java:4: error: class Layer1 is public, should be declared in a file named Layer1.java

Comment: Yes, you need to use **one-file-per-class** approach java uses. Unfortunately, this is not C#. :-)

Comment: But, then what is the package for? Do I need to have 3 files all package framework and each with one class?

Comment: @JamieFlowers: yes. In java, yes. `framework` will be a directory with three files: `Layer1`, `Layer2` and `Layer3`.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error, but i discovered that when I do <%@ page import="framework.*" %> Eclipse will not show an error.